# I have a side-by-side setup, using div containers (2 are in one container), and I can't get the right side to align to the top with my float right

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have figured out how to get my 2 sections to appear side-by-side within my div container. The left side is a slideshow & is exactly where/how I want it to appear, but the right side won't align to the top.

I have added extra verbiage to see if that would "push" it all to the top, but it kept going lower. I've tried adding vertical-align top to .alignright, along with all the other solutions for alignment I have found here & on other sites.

The alignright being a float to the right has to stay or the verbiage all shifts left, right up next to the slideshow (and looks horrible).
I've attached the current output.  "In the olden days" I would valign=top & then , but that has no effect.

```
<div class = "text">
<p class ="alignright">

Save a Life
<br>
images go here
<br>
Donate Now
<br>
TEXT

</p>
</div>



.alignright {
    float: right;
.text {
  color: #0000A0;
  font-family: Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif; 
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image: current output]

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
}

#left, #right{
border:solid 1px green;


}

#left {

margin-left:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div id = 'left'>x<br>x<br>x</div>
<div id = 'right'>x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already have the left side of the container working as the slideshow (the container is defined, sizes are set, and they all work).  I was hoping for a one-liner to make the right side of it bump to the top instead of the bottom/center. Goes back to my old motto - if at first you don't succeed, force the code to work how you want it to. =)

Comment: try adding display:table; vertical-align:middle; on the right div

Comment: It's still not aligning to the top, but it looks WAY better!  I was able to situate the donation buttons in between there, and make it look not as wonky.  Thank you!!

Comment: if you added a working snippet of what you have it would be easier to see what's going on

Comment: I found out a little bit ago that to make this site work on phones, I should basically scrap the css junk entirely, so I'm not sure I'm going to push forward with any of this right now lol.  Used to take me 2-3 hours to set up a whole site. Not sure why stuff had to be made so complicated. =\

Comment: if it's a web app you won't be able to scrap the css

Comment: I left just the slideshow & redid the site (in about 2 hours) & now everything lines up the way I want it to (on a PC, android & iPhone). Only CSS in the whole thing is just the slideshow. =) What I did will wind up making newer web developers (anyone who started coding after 2005) have their heads spin off, but it was SO much faster, is fully functional, and almost no stress. The CSS was a good learning experience though, as it gave me the ability to do the slideshow. =)  I appreciate the answers from before - made me realize I need to do it the most efficient way for me.